# Actualizar índice de carrito de compras

Tags: php, html, mysql, array

Estoy tratando de actualizar el índice de mi carrito de compras

```
session_start();
$spinner = $_POST['spinner'];
```

Del código de arriba, recibo un array, estos provienen de unos "input number" que tiene cada ITEM de mi carrito de compras y mi sesion carrito esta definida como

```
$_SESSION["carrito"]
```

Ahora, cada vez que yo agrego un nuevo item a mi carrito, la cantidad a vender por default en el INPUT number sale 1 oviamente todos los input number tienen como nombre:  name"spinner[]"

```
<input type="number" id="'.$producto->id_uniforme.'" name="spinner[]"  value="'.$producto->cantidad.'"></td>
```

Entonces como hago para que cuando le doy en terminar venta, se me actualice la cantidad de cada índice de mi carrito de compras con valor de cada INPUT NUMBER respectivo.

En el siguiente código, actualizo la cantidad del índice, pero en todos me sale el valor del ultimo input number.

```
foreach ($spinner as $retiro) { 

 for ($i = 0; $i < count($_SESSION["carrito"]); $i++) {

      $_SESSION["carrito"][$i]->cantidad = $retiro;                   
 }
 }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos.

Comment: Tienes que sumar `$retiro` al valor que ya exista, haciendo algo así más o menos: `$_SESSION["carrito"][$i]->cantidad =$_SESSION["carrito"][$i]->cantidad  +  $retiro;`

Comment: Creo que su problema es que se le asigna el ultimo valor del input a todas las posiciones debido al bucle anidado, un saludo! @A.Cedano

Comment: @BoredGeek, cierto, cierto, hay que buscarlo de forma dinámica con  `$_POST['spinner'][$i]` como indicas en tu respuesta. Auque en ese caso el primer `foreach` sobra, y, supogno que los datos están sincronizados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema lo tienes en el for anidado dentro del foreach. Cuando realizas el foreach recorres todos los spinner[] recibidos, de esta manera cuando llegas a la ultima vuelta, al hacer un for dentro le asignas el ultimo valor del spinner[] a todos los items del carrito.

Como ya he dicho, el bucle anidado sobra. Una posible solución:

```
 for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['spinner']); $i++) {

      $_SESSION["carrito"][$i]->cantidad = $_POST['spinner'][$i];                   
 }
```